# Bold the name of the speaker on specific frame

Tags: beamer

I have three speakers on the title frame as follow:

```
\author{Mister X, Mister Y, Mister Z}
```

I want to bold the name **Mister X** on frame 1 and 2 and **Mister Y** on frame 3 and 4 for example. I haven't found the solution; the content of `\author` can't be overwritten.

It's possible to do that with beamer?

Regards

Here is a small code to illustrate:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usepackage[french]{babel}  

\title{My Talk}
\subtitle{All authors must be here}
\author{Mister X, Mister Y, Mister Z}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Mister X's part}   

\frame{
\frametitle{Part of Mister X}

"Mister X" must be bold in the footer.

}

\section{Mister Y's part}   

\frame{
\frametitle{Part of MisterY}

"Mister Y" must be bold in the footer.

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you include a small example together with the theme you are using for us to test?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've edit my message to add example code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test the number of the frame by `\value{framenumber}` and modify the optional argument of `\author`. The conditional `\ifcase` test the number of the value and use the given definition. Note that `\ifcase` starts at 0.

```
\author[%
     \ifcase\value{framenumber}
     \or%1
        Mister X, Mister Y, Mister Z
    \or%2
        \textbf{Mister X}, Mister Y, Mister Z
    \or%3
         Mister X, \textbf{Mister Y}, Mister Z
    \else%4,5,...
        Mister X, Mister Y, Mister Z
    \fi%
     ]{Mister X, Mister Y, Mister Z}
```

Here your example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usepackage[french]{babel}  

  \title{My Talk}
  \subtitle{All authors must be here}
  \author[%
     \ifcase\value{framenumber}
     \or%1
        Mister X, Mister Y, Mister Z
    \or%2
        \textbf{Mister X}, Mister Y, Mister Z
    \or%3
         Mister X, \textbf{Mister Y}, Mister Z
    \else%4,5,...
        Mister X, Mister Y, Mister Z
    \fi%
     ]{Mister X, Mister Y, Mister Z}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Mister X's part}   

\frame{
\frametitle{Part of Mister X}

"Mister X" must be bold in the footer.

}

\section{Mister Y's part}   

\frame{
\frametitle{Part of MisterY}
   "Mister Y" must be bold in the footer.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution can be done more elegant if you want to use something like `\misterxslide{1,2,3}\misteryslide{5,6,7}`.